# Multiple checkbox with reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a checkbox child functional component in react. It takes function and data as props.I must pass item state to parent component and keep them in state array actually.

I want to keep selected items in state, and show them. I tried many ways for example in checkbox `checked={isSelected.includes(item.id)}` but always it gives error.

my checkbox.js is like that:

```js
function CheckboxList(/*{ onSelectedFilter,data }*/) {
  const [isSelected, setSelected] = React.useState({})
  const [checked,setChecked]= React.useState()
  
 //---
 //temporary (passed as props)
  const data = [{id:"1",text:"Product 2"},{id:"2",text:"Product 3"},{id:"3",text:"Product 14"},{id:"6",text:"Product 41"},{id:"7",text:"Prdoduct 1"}]

  const onSelectedFilter=(item)=>{
    setChecked(!item.checked)
    setSelected({...isSelected, [item.id] : checked});
    //setSelected([...isSelected,item.id])
    console.log(item.id," ", item.text," ",isSelected)
  }
  //---

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("checkedItems: ", isSelected);
  }, [isSelected]);  

  return (
    <div className="checkbox-list">
        <ul>
          {data.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <label htmlFor={item.text} className="checkbox">
                <span className="input">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id={item.text}
                    name="checkbox-list"
                    value={item.text}
                    checked={item.selected}
                    onClick={() => onSelectedFilter(item)}
                  />
                  <span className="control" />
                </span>
                <span className="label">{item.text}</span>
              </label>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<CheckboxList />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, one approach might be to have a `onSelectedFilter` function (in the parent component) that looks something like:

```js
function onSelectedFilter(indexToUpdate) {
  setItems(prev => [
    ...prev.slice(0, indexToUpdate),
    { ...prev[indexToUpdate], selected: !prev[indexToUpdate] }, 
    ...prev.slice(indexToUpdate+ 1)
  ]);
}
```

and then, in the child component, you provide a concrete value for `indexToUpdate` whilst mapping over the array:

```js
{
  data.map((item, index) => (
    <li key={item.id}>
      <label htmlFor={item.text} className="checkbox">
        <span className="input">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id={item.text}
            name="checkbox-list"
            value={item.text}
            checked={item.selected}
            onClick={() => onSelectedFilter(index)}
          />
          <span className="control" />
        </span>
        <span className="label">{item.text}</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  ));
}
```

This then means that the child doesn't need to have any state. It just accepts some props from its parent, one of which happens to be a function that prompts the parent to update a particular object.

---

Side note: Instead of `indexToUpdate`, you could also just have the child pass the `item.id` back to the parent, or the entire `item` (but then you'd need to change the body/implementation of `onSelectedFilter` in the parent component to work with `item.id` or `item` instead).